# Remote Execution working on local PC

Tags: remote, rpc

i'm working on a project where i need to do some stuff with remote computers. My problem is that i need to execute some program on a remote machine, but working on my computer. To be more specific, i want to run notepad.exe (or any program) on my computer but the execution is assigned to the remote computer.

I've trying with RPC but i think it's just running a program on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing install teamviewer or vnc client on your machine and access your remote machine and just execute normal commands

Comment: Thanks for your help but i can't use VNC or Teamviewer. What i need it's like an application running on my desktop, but the execution is made by the remote computer.

Comment: @user1586264: You might have to explain *why* you believe you can't use VNC or Teamviewer. Can you use Remote Desktop? These are the programs that are designed to solve your exact problem.

Comment: I can't use those programs because i need to manage the communication on CMD. It's like an application server.